# Unignore ignored files by child repository in the parent repository

Tags: git

We have two repositories, `RepoA` and `RepoB`.

```
├───RepoA
│   ├───SomeDirectory
│   │   ├───RepoB
│   │   │   ├───TargetFile.ext
│   │   │   ├───TargetFile.metadata
│   │   │   └───.gitignore (3)
│   │   └───.gitignore (2)
│   ├───.gitignore (1)
│   └───SomeOtherDirectories
```

The file `.gitignore(2)` ignores `RepoB` directory so it won't be tracked (I know there are other approaches for having multi repositories.)
The file `.gitignore(3)` ignores `*.metadata` so they won't be tracked for `RepoB`.
Now for every `.ext` file to work correctly in `RepoA` there is a `.metadata` generated. The metadata files are important and I intend to include them in my commits in `RepoA` but I don't want them to appear in `RepoB`. Can I somehow ignore the rules of `.gitignore(3)` while working on `RepoA`? Or can I include some of the files in `RepoB` directory in my `RepoA` repository?

I tried several things with no luck:

- Added `!RepoB/*.metadata` to `.gitignore(2)` but git didn't see the file.
- Removed every rule in `.gitignore(2)` but the only change detected by git was the directory `RepoB` which had no content in it.
- Added explicit unignore for the metadata `!RepoB/TargetFile.metadata` but didn't work.

Comment: You can't do that. A repository will never hold another repository, and as a result, the Git for RepoA won't look inside of, nor interfere with, the Git for RepoB except to record the submodule gitlink hash ID. Meanwhile the Git for RepoB will not look at any of the files in RepoA at all.

Comment: What this means is that if you want RepoA to hold these `.metadata` files, you must put them in a directory that resides *within* RepoA itself. You can then copy those files *into* the `RepoB` working tree later, manually.

Comment: Thanks, if it's not possible in any way, then you would want to post an answer. The framework I'm using manages the `.metadata` files. Having them copied elsewhere will result in framework removing them, having them removed in the first place causes them to be regenerated. I think my only option is to include them in RepoB.